# How to play video in react.js using html video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Does anyone know why my video does not load? It shows the player but no video.

```
  class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <p>hello</p>
      <video width="750" height="500" controls >
      <source src="..Videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
     </video>
      </div>
    );
  }   
}
```

This is how my directory is structured:

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLAGf.png)
[React App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY1J9.png)

I tried this as suggested: `src="../Videos/video1.mp4"` and I get the same result

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This may be due to a number of factors, namely, your server's configuration.

Assuming that your server is able to serve mp4 files correctly, and is running from the `my-app` directory, then you should be able to resolve the issue by adding a `/` to the beginning of your `src` attribute:

```
<source src="/Videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

If you've created your project via `create-react-app`, then you will want to create a `Videos` folder under the `public` directory, and put your video file there, seeing this is where public assets are served from by default.

So, put your video file in `my-app/public/Videos/video1.mp4`. Then clear your browser cache, and rebuild and reload your app.

Comment: I am using the server that is created automatically when you do create-react-app from the github page https://github.com/facebook/react

Comment: Is there any reason why it would not load the files?

Comment: Please see updated answer with more detailed instruction

Comment: Hey it worked thank you! I used this directory after putting the Videos folder in the public directory. ../public/../Videos/video1.mp4

Answer (score 34):

I also landed in this same issue a few days back ago, but I found out the original way of solving this issue with the native React.JS style.

for your scenario, lets say you want to import video locally in your project file into react app then,
instead of using native HTML syntax for eg:

```
<video width="750" height="500" controls >
      <source src="./Videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

which for me didn't worked for me in my case for my project. So I just slightly modified the code in following manner and it worked flawlessly.

You need to import the video as a certain entity in react just like how to import any other npm packages/modules

for eg in you your case you need to do these slight changes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import video from './Videos.video1.mp4'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <p>hello</p>
      <video width="750" height="500" controls >
      <source src={video} type="video/mp4"/>
     </video>
      </div>
    );
  }   
}
```

or

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import video from './Videos.video1.mp4'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <p>hello</p>
      <video src={video} width="750" height="500" controls>
     </video>
      </div>
    );
  }   
}
```

this will also work well without using `<source>` tag

Comment: Thanks a lot! At first, I got a TypeScript error, but then instead of using `import` I used `require` and everything worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 3):

You missed a forward slash `/`. It should be `<source src="../Videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>`

Comment: That's the correct relative path from your file. Alternatively, you can put the Video folder in the public directory and use `<source src="/Videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>` . Does the console show any error?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'require' function, like this:

```
<video width="auto" height="auto" autoplay>
  <source src={require('../assets/video.mp4')} type="video/ogg"/>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I import the video in react.js and that's works for me.

```
import video from "./video.mp4";
```

Answer (score 0):

This you will be able to use video tag like and if you want to make it play infinity time you can set autoPlay and loop

```
<div className="w-full h-screen relative">
      <video autoPlay loop muted className="w-full h-full object-cover">
           <source src={Loader} type="video/mp4" />
           Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
</div>
```

you can give the path for the video in this way ...

> import Loader from '../../assets/loader.mp4'

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue and replaced the video element with the self closing iFrame element instead for react.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35717879)